# git: how to be able to switch branches again

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, git-merge

I had a lot of uncommitted changes, which is bad practice.
I have tried to slowly commit all my important changes.

I was trying to reorganize work across branches, so I did (starting from my master with changes):

```
git checkout -b Feature1
git commit somestuff -ma'msg'
git push remote/Feature1 
git checkout -b Feature2
git commit otherstuff -ma'msg'
git push remote/Feature1 
...
```

for multiple branches.
Then I discovered my starting master was not updated when I have started, so I have done

```
git fetch 
git checkout Feature1
git merge origin/master
git checkout Feature2
git merge origin/master
...
```

Then I should have been up to date and clean.
Then I have modified some stuff in `Feature2`. Now I would like to switch to `Feature1`. However it says

```
you have local changes in X; you can't switch branches
```

But I have just committed and pushed my changes to `X` to `Feature2`.
What am I doing wrong?

---

If I do

```
git diff X > atextfile
```

`atextfile` shows the entire X has changed, but if I compare the two versions tagged with - + they are identical

```
git diff --check X
```

returns only trailing whitespace differences. How to get rid of those?

Comment: if `git status` is clean you should not see this error.

Comment: git status is not clean: it says .... no changes added to commit. and lists tons of stuff as modified, including X which is on my latest line if it do git log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status` will show you what has changed including the changed file X and `git diff X` will show the change.

If you want to move this change into Feature1 you can do a checkout with merge flag, which merges across the changes `git checkout -m Feature1`.

Comment: thanks. I would be ready for a checkout -m. However, some of the changes I see with git diff where never done by me on this branch (and by no one else on this branch since I have just created it) so I am not sure if it is the right thing to do

Comment: Is it possible your merge of master into Feature2 didn't complete or end up committed? That's the only thing that comes to mind if you're seeing lots of unexpected changes.

Comment: how can I check ?normally I would do via GUIs, but now I only have CLI

Comment: if I diff a single one, I see no changes between the version with - and with +

Comment: can this be a CLRF issue

Comment: Does a `git diff --check` or `git diff -R` show any changes to the files? Apparently those should help to show changes to trailing whitespace or line endings.

Comment: and yes: check says trailing whitespace.how to fix this issue?

Comment: If it's _only_ trailing whitespace, then you could checkout all the changed files to throw away the changes.